# SFML - Not displaying Text

Tags: c++, text, sfml

Playing around with SFML, I do set a font but it still does not want to display the text. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Owen

```
// Choose a font
Font font;
font.loadFromFile("fonts/arial.tff");

// Set our message font
scoreText.setFont(font);

scoreText.setString("Score = 0");
scoreText.setCharacterSize(100);

// Choose a color
scoreText.setFillColor(Color::White);

// Position the text
scoreText.setPosition(20, 20);

window.draw(scoreText);
window.display();
```

Comment: where is window.clear() ? Also make sure you don't draw on a white background.

Comment: put font.loadFromFile("fonts/arial.tff"); in a condition too, in order to check if the font is loaded

Comment: the window.clear is there, forgot to include it and the background is empty. I think the font is not being loaded so the path to the font may be incorrect.

Comment: @pmaxim98 how do I build that condition? will it look like this?

    if (!font.loadFromFile("font/arial.tff")
    {
        // Error message?
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Firstly: To be able to use your font it must be present in the **fonts** folder in the **main** folder of your project, otherwise the function `loadFromFile()` should returns a false, but note that this is written in the official documentation :

> The loadFromFile function can sometimes fail with no obvious reason

-Secondly: as mentioned by @pmaxim98, you need to call the `clear()` function before drawing anything, and the color argument should be different from the text fill color so that you can view the displayed text.

-Thirdly: try to put the font file in the main folder of your project and try this minimal code :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{

RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800,600),"TEXT");

/****************************************************/

//Declare a Font object
Font font;

//Load and check the availability of the font file
if(!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
{
    cout << "can't load font" << endl;
}

//Declare a Text object
Text text("Score = 0",font);

//Set character size
text.setCharacterSize(100);

//Set fill color
text.setFillColor(Color::White);

/****************************************************/


while(window.isOpen())
{
    Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event))
    {
         if(event.type == Event::Closed){window.close();}
    }

    //Clear the window
    window.clear();
    //Draw the text
    window.draw(text);
    //Display the text to the window
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why but I copied and pasted the arial font from system fonts. I have now downloaded a royalty free font and it works. Thanks everyone for the answers